# How can I retrieve all of the tags for each database record (many-to-many relationship) and echo them as a list

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-design

I'm using CodeIgniter and MySQL. I'm using the following function in my model to retrieve all of the items in a table.

```
public function get_projects() {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('projects')
        ->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I then display the results in a view like this:

```
<?php foreach ($projects as $project) { ?>
<li><a href="#"><?php echo $project->title; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Now I want to list all of the tags for each item from the conjunction table that I have between a `Projects` table and a `Tags` table.

```
CREATE TABLE project_tags (
    'project_id' int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    'tag_id' varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Projects(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES Tags(id)
);
```

Now how can I add to my `get_projects()` function so that I can retrieve an array of the tags for each project?

I know I could possibly do a join query, however when I do that it returns multiple project titles because there's multiple tags, so the foreach loop in my view prints out duplicate titles.

Comment: Maybe you can try query like this:
    `SELECT
        Projects.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Tags.name) 
    FROM projects
    JOIN project_tags ON Projects.id= project_tags.project_id
    JOIN Tags ON Tags.id= project_tags.tag_id  
    GROUP BY Projects.id`
It's not tested.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing after reading the question that was linked.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function get_projects() {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('projects');
$this->db->join('project_tags ', 'project_tags .project_id =
projects.id','inner');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: I had tried this before and it worked as well but I think what I was really looking for was the GROUP_CONCAT, I just didn't know how to ask the question correctly. Thanks!